# How come ==np.nan in Python never works?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe with some nan values.  Every time I do something like df["column"] == np.nan, it always returns all False.  It never returns True even though there are obvoiusly nan.  I mean even this returns all false:

```
np.full(5, np.nan) == np.nan
```

Why?

Comment: Because [np.nan != np.nan](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing).

Comment: It's part of the C-heritage of Python: `NaN==NaN` equals `False`, and that's typically how you check for NaNs in C/C++.